# Annotation to make available generic type

Tags: java, generics, annotations

Given a generic interface like

```
interface DomainObjectDAO<T>
{
   T newInstance();
   add(T t);
   remove(T t);
   T findById(int id);
   // etc...    
}
```

I'd like to create a subinterface that specifies the type parameter:

```
  interface CustomerDAO extends DomainObjectDAO<Customer> 
  {
       // customer-specific queries - incidental.
  }
```

The implementation needs to know the actual template parameter type, but of course type erasure means it isn't available at runtime. Is there some annotation that I could include to declare the interface type? Something like

```
  @GenericParameter(Customer.class)
  interface CustomerDAO extends DomainObjectDAO<Customer> 
  {
  }
```

The implementation could then fetch this annotation from the interface and use it as a substitute for runtime generic type access.

Some background:

This interface is implemented using JDK dynamic proxies as outlined [here](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2003.html). The non-generic version of this interface has been working well, but it would be nicer to use generics and not have to create the methods in a subinterface just to specify the domain object type. Generics and proxies take care of most things, but the actual type is needed at runtime to implement the `newInstance` method, amongst others.

Comment: Have you tried to just write your own annotation?

Comment: @Lauri - I haven't made my own, but I could do that, I see a lot of questions about generics and frustrations over type erasure, so I'm hoping this has been done already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to find the actual type argument of the Dao sub-interface (CustomerDAO), by invoking the following method:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public static Class<?> getDomainClass(final Class<?> daoInterface) {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) daoInterface.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
    return (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

When you call it like

```
Class<?> domainClass = getDomainClass(daoInterface);
```

with `daoInterface == CustomerDAO.class`, then you will get `domainClass == Customer.class`.

In my implementation, a `DaoFactory` performs this call and uses the `domainClass` as a constructor argument for the `DaoInvocationHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution. According to http://blog.springsource.com/2006/09/29/exploiting-generics-metadata/ not all generic information is erased - in particular, static information is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

> The implementation needs to know the actual template parameter type.

Surely, any implementation of `CustomerDao` implicitly *knows* that the type parameter is `Customer`.  It is implementing `DomainObjectDAO<Customer>` not `DomainObjectDAO<T>`.

Problems are only going to arise if the `CustomerDao` class extends a generic abstract class, and that generic abstract class needs to know the actual type of `T`.  But you can deal with that by passing the Class object for `T` (in this case `Customer.class`) to the superclass as a constructor argument.

Comment: I was going to write that in the question that I could pass the actual type as a constructor to the InvocationHandler, but I was wondering if there is an annotation to do the same job - the type belongs to the interface and not the implementation.